# socket program - reliable data transfer using UDP

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have written code for reliable data transfer in C. Here the client sends the file to the server in chunks of 1024 bytes. And the server writes the packets received into another file.

The program works fine for string file/binary data file. But when I try to copy image file there comes the problem.   when I try transferring .jpg file there is no compilation error or run time error. But when I try opening the destination file it says,
"could not open image file','error interpreting jpeg file' ' improper call to jpeg library in state 201".

Can anybody look into the codes and suggest any solution?

Here is my client code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

char *itoa(long i,char *s,int dummy_radix)
{
    sprintf(s,"%ld",i);
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    int sock,length,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server,from;
    struct hostent *hp;
    long int packets =0;
    unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};

    // checking if hostname and the port address is provided //
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("insufficient arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //create a socket//
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    if(sock<0)
    {
        printf("error in opening socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //to get  the hostname of the system or the machine//
    hp= gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(hp==0)
    {
        printf("Unknown host\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //build the server's IP address //
    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    bcopy((char*)hp->h_addr,(char *)&server.sin_addr,hp->h_length);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port =  htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    length = sizeof(server);

    /*open the file that we wish to transfer*/
    FILE *fp = fopen("landscape.jpeg","rb");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("file open error");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); //if exists read the size of the file 
    size_t file_size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET); 

    printf("size of the file is %d\n", file_size);

    /*find the number of packets*/
    packets = (file_size/1024)+1 ;

    /*send the number of packets to the server*/
    itoa(packets,buff,10);
    n = sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if(n<0)
    {
        printf("error in sending message to the serveR");
        return 1;
    }

    /*Read data from file and send it*/
    int packetNum = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        /*First read file in chunks of  1024  bytes */
        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);
        //printf("Bytes read %d\n",nread);

        /*if read was success ,send data*/
        if(nread>0)
        {
            //printf("data sent now is %s\n",buff);
            n = sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            printf("Sending %d, numBytes sent: %d\n", packetNum, n);
            packetNum++;
            if(n<0)
            {
                printf("error in sending message to the server");
                fclose(fp);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        /*There is something tricky going on with the read..
         * Either there was error ,or we reached end of  file.
         */
        if(nread<1024)
        {
            if(feof(fp))
                printf("End of file\n");

            if(ferror(fp))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    close(sock);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my server code

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock,length,fromlen,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    char buf[1024];
    char file_buf[1024];
    int packets = 0;
    int received = 0;
    FILE *newfp;
    newfp = fopen("output.jpeg","wb");
    if(newfp==NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening the file\n");
        return 1;
    }    
    if(argc<2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no port number specified\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sock<0)
    {
        printf("error in opening socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    length = sizeof(server);
    bzero(&server,length);
    server.sin_family= AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&server,length)<0)
    {
        printf("cannot bind\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    n = recvfrom(sock,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);
    if(n<0)
    {
        printf("recvfrom  error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    packets = atoi(buf);
    printf("Num packets expected: %d\n", packets);

    while(received<packets)
    {
        n = recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof (buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);    

        //printf ("%d\n", n);
        printf("Packet num %d, numBytes received: %d\n", received, n);

        if(n<0)
        {
            printf("recvfrom  error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //printf("%s",buf);
        if((fwrite(buf,1,n,newfp)) < n)
        {
            printf("error in writing to the file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        received++;
    }
    printf("Finished\n");
    fclose(newfp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to do that if you don’t include the code.

Comment: 'It displays error' is not a problem description.

Comment: It looks like you’re relying on UDP packets arriving in order (or at all), but that’s not necessarily the case. Try some text that’s long enough to get split across multiple chunks. Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Yes it works fine for text that is long enough. The problem is with the .jpg file or any other image file.

Comment: You are assuming that `fread()` null-terminates the buffer: it doesn't; and that the data doesn't contain other nulls: it can. You should use `nread` instead of `strlen(buffer)` as the count parameter when sending the file data. And the correct test for end of file is not `nread < 1024`, which can happen any time: it is `nread == 0`.

Comment: @EJP I corrected my mistakes in the code.Unfortunately I still have the error with .jpg files. It says could not load image file if I try opening it after running my program:(                                                                                            The corrections I made were on the lines  n= sendto(sock,buff,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)); and to check end of file I  have to check (n==0) But that did not solve my issues.

Comment: `sendto(sock,buff,1024, ...)` should be `sendto(sock,buff,nread, ...)`. I already stated that clearly. And you still aren't handling out of sequence packets, or missing or duplicated ones. In fact there is nothing reliable about this code at all. You need sequence numbers *in the packets*, which are removed when writing the data to the file; you need an ACK or NACK mechanism for missing packets; you need a mechanism that ignores duplicates; ... You've barely started.

Comment: ok. I will improve my code

Comment: tcp an option? Unless this is an assignment specifically about writing a reliable protocol, just use tcp. I never understand people trying to morph udp into reliability. A reliable protocol already exists (although somewhat bloated).. use it!  /rant. Now, I also highly recommend using some kind of packet capture tool (wireshark, tcpdump, message analyzer, etc) so you know exactly what you're sending. Forget the pictures, use big files of known data. Hash them on both sides. Keep decreasing file size until you get hashes that match. This should help narrow down when the problem manifests.

Comment: You can also heavily decrease your packet size and use smaller files. Send 5 bytes a packet for a 20 byte file, then for a 23 byte file (something not evenly divisible). This will be far easier to keep a handle on what's happening. You say it works fine for a string, maybe you're just getting some extra junk at the end that you're not seeing in notepad. If it was working for binary files, then it would also be working for .jpegs. If you're getting some junk at the end or something, the jpeg view may not know what to do with that and then it complains.

Comment: @EJP ..I could fix the bug with your suggestions. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are assuming that `fread()` null-terminates the buffer. It doesn't.
2. You are assuming that the data doesn't contain other nulls: it can.
3. You should use `nread` instead of `strlen(buffer)` as the count parameter when sending the file data.
4. The correct test for end of file is not `nread < 1024`, which can happen any time: it is `nread == 0`.
5. You aren't handling out of sequence packets, or missing or duplicated ones. In fact there is nothing reliable about this code at all. You need sequence numbers in the packets, which are removed when writing the data to the file; you need an ACK or NACK mechanism for missing packets; you need a mechanism that ignores duplicates; ...

You've barely started.